# Comó generar una aplicacion .EXE compuesta con varios .py?

Tags: python

Como hago para generer un solo .exe en PY el cual tiene una pantalla principal y varios MENUS de opciones los cuales son distintos .PY, es decir una pantalla para ingresar a un clientes, otro para cargar datos de una compra, etc....

Comment: Que compilador de exe usas? Pyinstaller, py2exe. etc?

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, para poder crear un .exe usa la libreria pyinstaller, puedes ver su documentación aquí: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Ahora si lo que quieres es usar varios .py, lo que debes hacer es modular todo el proyecto, para esto comenzamos creando un .py principal donde importes y ejecutes las funciones de las demas, para esto debes tener un archivo llamado `__init__.py` en la carpeta raiz y en cada carpeta que halla un archivo a importar, este archivo puede estar vacio, solamente debe existir.

Ahora en el archivo principal, debes importar los demas de esta forma:

```
from archivo import funcion   #Si esta en la misma carpeta
from carpeta.archive import funcion    #Si esta dentro de una carpeta
```

(No hay que colocar la extension .py ahí)

Ahora para crear el exe, instalas la libreria py2exe

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Ahora nos dirigimos a la carpeta del proyecto y colocamos

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile archive.py   #Aqui colocamos el archivo principal que importa los demas .py
```

Y listo.

Comment: Si no me entendiste, dime y te doy una explicación mas detallada.

Comment: primero debes de conocer la estructura del proyecto, luego debes saber si esta usando algún compilador de exe, si no lo usa, en ese caso su pregunta estaría pidiendo recomendaciones de herramientas. Es mas preferible dejar un comentario pidiendo aclaraciones, pero igual me gusto tu respuesta